# Getting total count from the string

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string "Economy 1 bed, type 452, lcd 4 king bed , 11 queen bed". 
From the above string, I have asked to get the count like 1+4=5. 
If the number greater than 10 in the given string , then ignore that number to add(So ignore 452 and 11).
Can anyone write logic for this ??

```
String a="Economy Double , 1 queen bed 42 lcd";
int sum = 0;
String num = "";
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
        num = num + a.charAt(i);
    } else {
        if(!num.equals("")) {
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num);
            num = "";
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: share what you have tried out

Comment: We won't do this for you, but we can definitely help you - how did you think to solve this problem?

Comment: This site is not a code writing service. Try to solve the problem yourself and come back when you have specific problems.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, I most definitely can. If you want actual help, you should show some effort first though.

Comment: String a="Economy Double , 1 queen bed 42 lcd";
     int sum = 0;
     String num = "";
     for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
         if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
          num = num + a.charAt(i);
         } else {
             if(!num.equals("")) {
                 sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num);
                 num = "";
             }
         }
     }
     System.out.println(sum);

Comment: This is what I tried

Comment: Can we assume that the numbers are allways started or followed by a space? If thats the case one idea would be to start by splitting your string by space. After that remove eventual punctuation marks from your splitted parts, check if remaining size is == 1 and if it can be parsed as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only need to consider numbers < 10, then this should do it (quick and dirty and slow):

```
    String a = "1 Economy 1 bed, type 452, lcd 4 king bed , 11 queen bed 2";
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
       char currChar = a.charAt(i);
       if(Character.isDigit(currChar)) {
        if(i -1 >= 0 && i+1 < a.length() && !Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i+1)) && !Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i-1))){
          sum += Character.getNumericValue(currChar);
        }else if(i+1 >= a.length() && !Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i-1))){
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(currChar);
        }else if(i == 0 &&  !Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i+1))){
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(currChar);
        }
       } 
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Except that is doesn't care about numbers > 10.

Comment: Yes sure, but he only wants to consider numbers <10?

Comment: It's adding all digits. I want to add numbers less than 10.

Comment: As a result I got 43 . but I want 1 as answer. because 42 is > 10

Comment: I've updated my answer, you need to check the next and previous characters in order to rule out numbers > 10

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is correct. Just add the condition in this line:

```
sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num);
```

And change it to:

```
sum += (Integer.parseInt(num)<10 ? Integer.parseInt(num) : 0);
```